# AspHostPortal SmtpMail doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I recently bought a hosting service plan and domaine name on AspHostPortal (almost 2 months ago)

Plan: Host One

http://asphostportal.com/ASPNET-MVC-Hosting.aspx

On the service Plan they are saying that i have :

**Email Specs**

200 MB Email Space

Unlimited POP3/SMTP

Unlimited Domain Aliases

Unlimited Domain Forwarders

Unlimited Auto Responders

SmarterMail Access

Catch All

0 Mailing Lists

and they refer me to this link to be able to send email, http://faq.asphosthelpdesk.com/article.php?id=83

i tried with my credentials and it still doesn't work.

Should i be able to send email with the hosting service?

Do i missunderstand the service plan ?

the hosting helpdesk are telling that they cannot do anything to help me!...

Answer (score 0):

Ok we got it working

we were using HostingPlan Account and Password and we needed to user EmailAccount and the EmailPassword !

Pretty easy when you know it!

Comment: Can you please give the settings that you are using (host, port, ssl/tls, etc)? I have the same plan as you. When I ask them for the settings, they tell me that I can not send email from my application unless I purchase their Business Email accounts.

Comment: i left AspHostPortal.... they are stealings your money and doesnt give any services.

Comment: I confirmed that hosted apps can no longer send emails without a business email. The cheapest is their "al-la-carte" plan for $2/month for one address. I was told that I could send email with SMTP via an outside provider to avoid paying this. Who did you switch to?

Answer (score 0):

All in here.

https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/a2-hosting-products/windows-hosting/using-asp-net-to-send-e-mail-messages#C-example

From my config file.

```
<mailSettings>
      <smtp from="noreply@goldendate.co.uk">
        <network enableSsl="false" 
defaultCredentials="false" host="yourdomain" 
password="yourpassword" port="25" 
userName="youremailaddress" />
</mailSettings>
```